# Display form validation errors next to each field

Tags: php, forms, validation

I am working on a simple contact form written in php and have almost everything setup as I would like for it to be except right now, all validation errors are displaying in a div on the top of my form, and I would like to change the code below so they are displayed next to the form field that caused the error, but I am not sure how to accomplish this so I have come to the experts for some advise.

**PHP Validation Routine**

```
$frm_valid = new Validate();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$rules=array(
    array('Type'=>'Required','Var'=>$_POST['name'],'Msg'=>'Name field is required.'),
    array('Type'=>'Required','Var'=>$_POST['email'],'Msg'=>'Email address field is required.'),
    array('Type'=>'Email','Var'=>$_POST['email'],'Msg'=>'Your email address format is invalid.'),
    array('Type'=>'Required','Var'=>$_POST['subject'],'Msg'=>'Subject field is required.'),
    array('Type'=>'Required','Var'=>$_POST['message'],'Msg'=>'Message field is required.'),
);


$result = $frm_valid->Valid($rules);

if(is_array($result)){
    // Print validation errors (if any)
    echo('<div"><b>The form cannot be submitted until the following errors are corrected.</b><ul>');

    foreach($result as $key=>$val){
      echo '<li>'.$val.'</li>';
    }
    echo('</ul></div><br />');
  } 
  else {
    // Do something else.
  }
}
```

**Forms HTML**

```
<form action="<? echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" /> <br />

    <input type="text" name="email" value="" />  <br />

    <input type="text" name="subject" value="" /> <br />

    <textarea name="message" cols="80" rows="7"></textarea> <br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Comment: would using html5's validation feasible? something like this `http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/`

Comment: I still get many visitors on my site that use IE7 (who knows why) and so an HTML5 solution will be out of the question here. I wish it were that simple tho.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change the whole code for this!!! The structure, perhaps this way:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label>
                <span>Name</span>
                <input type="text" name="name" />
                <small class="errorText"><?php echo ($_POST["name"] == "") ? "This field is required" : ""; ?></small>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <span>Email</span>
                <input type="text" name="email" />
                <small class="errorText"><?php echo ($_POST["email"] == "") ? "This field is required" : ""; ?></small>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <span>Subject</span>
                <input type="text" name="subject" />
                <small class="errorText"><?php echo ($_POST["subject"] == "") ? "This field is required" : ""; ?></small>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <span>Message</span>
                <textarea name="message" cols="80" rows="7"></textarea>
                <small class="errorText"><?php echo ($_POST["message"] == "") ? "This field is required" : ""; ?></small>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

And the CSS for the same:

```
* {font-family: Segoe UI, Tahoma;}
h1 {font-weight: bold; font-size: 14pt; padding: 5px 0; margin: 5px 0; border: 1px solid #999; border-width: 1px 0;}
input[type='submit'] {padding: 5px 20px; cursor: pointer;}
ul, li {display: block; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
ul li {padding: 5px 0;}
ul li label span {display: block; cursor: pointer;}
ul li label .errorText {color: #f00; font-weight: bold; vertical-align: top;}
ul li label textarea {width: 300px;}
```

You can see a live demo here: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JHE22/)

### Error Handling in PHP

Keep an error variable for each field. Say,

```
<?php
    $error = array(
        "name" => "",
        "email" => "",
        "subject" => "",
        "message" => ""
    );
?>
```

Update them with the errors and display them below.

```
<?php
    if (empty()$_POST["email"])
        $error["email"] = "Email is required!";
    elseif (!isEmail($_POST["email"]))
        $error["email"] = "Not a Valid Email!";
?>
```

If there are no errors, it would be empty and the user doesn't see the error message. In your Forms Code, you need to just update this way:

```
<small class="errorText"><?php echo $error["name"]; ?></small>
<small class="errorText"><?php echo $error["email"]; ?></small>
```

where in the backend, the `$error["email"]` would have either `"This field is required"` or `"Not a valid email address!"`.

Comment: So there is no way to alter the foreach loop to echo out the error message next to the form field that caused the error. The reason I am asking is because I am using a custom validation class which my site relies on for all my forms validation and it would be a very daunting task to change the entire way the system works just to get the error messages to display how I want them to.

Comment: This is pretty good. I like that the fields and error are wrapped in the label, so that clicking the error focuses on the field. I would add that it would be better UX and more modern if the errors were simply hidden via CSS and the form was validated via JS or AJAX and the messages revealed when appropriate, rather than reloading the form.

Comment: @nosx - If your system uses a validation class, I would request them via ajax and insert them as shown in Praveen's example. Is the issue that your PHP is nailed down, or the front end?

Comment: @nosx You need to have some kind of an element after the input tag. You don't need to update the PHP code. Just the HTML code will do, as you will be putting the error message here itself na?

Comment: The code `<?php echo ($_POST["message"] == "") ? "This field is required" : ""; ?>` does the trick. No need to alter the for loop, in fact, no need to touch it too!!!

Comment: yeah The front end is pretty well setup as it needs to be and the whole point is to validate on the backend if someone decides to turn their JS off for whatever reason so the ajax method is a no-go.

Comment: @Praveen I just read your comment again, and if I understand you correctly, I just need to update the "forms" code and leave the php code as it is now with no alterations at all ?

Comment: @nosx Exactly! You don't need to touch the PHP Code.. Just the forms code is enough!!! :) *PS: I am an UX Architect!* :)

Comment: @Praveen Hmm, still not sure how this is going to work since each field can have multiple rules applied to each (notice how the email field has 2 rules applied to it "Required & Email") I guess it's late for me and I am not seeing how this all fits, but I cannot see how your example will work in that case.

Comment: Okay in that case, you can do this way. Keep an error variable for each field. Say, `$error = array("name" => "", "email" => "");` Update them with the errors and display them below. If there are no errors, it would be empty and the user doesn't see the error message. In your Forms Code, you need to just update this way: `<?php echo $error["name"]; ?>` or `<?php echo $error["email"]; ?>`, where in the backend, the `$error["email"]` would have either `"This field is required"` or `"Not a valid email address!"`! What say?

Comment: Please check out the **Error Handling in PHP** which I updated in the answer. :)

Comment: For the sake of not letting this drag on I will accept your answer even tho I will not be able to use it since I am already using a custom validation class that does everything your suggestion I do with regards to handling different error types. This will still be useful to others tho I am sure. Thx

Comment: @nosx Thanks, welcome and glad that it was useful! :) PS: Now you can upvote answers. You got a new privilege! Congrats! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following way if your every field has a single error :

```
  <input name='myfield'>
     @if ($errors->has('myfield'))
        <span style="color:red;">
            {{ $errors->first('myfield') }}
        </span>
     @endif
```