# HTML form error handling

Tags: php, html, forms

I found on another question ([Display form validation errors next to each field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237655/display-form-validation-errors-next-to-each-field)) the following code:

```
 <?php
        $error = array(
            "name" => "",
            "email" => "",
            "subject" => "",
            "message" => ""
        );
    ?>

    <?php
        if (empty($_POST["email"]))
            $error["email"] = "Email is required!";
        elseif (!isEmail($_POST["email"]))
            $error["email"] = "Not a Valid Email!";
    ?>
```

If there are no errors, it would be empty and the user doesn't see the error message.

In your Forms Code, you need to just update this way:

```
    <small class="errorText"><?php echo $error["name"]; ?></small>
    <small class="errorText"><?php echo $error["email"]; ?></small>
```

where in the backend, the `$error["email"]` would have either `"This field is required"` or `"Not a valid email address!"`.

I tried to apply this to my code:

so I pasted the php section above in email.php and I updated my form like so:

```
    <form id="contacts-form" method="post" action="email.php" target="myiframe" >
       <fieldset>
       <div class="field">
          <label>Your E-mail:</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" value=""/>
          <small class="errorText"><?php echo $error["email"]; ?></small>
       </div>
       ...
```

now I get an error saying $error is not defined. Please bare in mind that Im new to php/HTML design and I am trying to learn by example

Thanks

Comment: Have you included `$error = array(...` statement too in your file?

Comment: no I put this statement in email.php

Comment: Be careful, it is NOT `if (empty()$_POST["email"])` but `if (empty($_POST["email"]))`.

Comment: yeah sorry I already fixed that part :) Ill update my post

Comment: OK! Also keep in mind that your if/elseif does not include all the cases, so when it is neither `if` neither `elseif`, will have a default value.

Comment: the problem am I having is that the variable $error defined in email.php cannot be seen by my form after I press submit, how can I solve this part?

Answer (score 0):

First off you should fix this line,

```
if (empty()$_POST["email"])
```

it should be

```
if (empty($_POST["email"]))
```

Secondly, the error is displayed because you probably do not define $error in the form. To check whether error has been defined you can use it like this

```
<?php echo isset($error['name'])?$error['name']:""; ?>
```

Also mind, that, to show the errors with this setup you should point the form to the same file your form is in.

Read about isset [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Read about the syntax [here](http://www.php.net/ternary#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Comment: I updated my php call from the form, I don't have an error anymore but nothing is displayed when I submit the form. From what I gathered, with this check we now can verify if $error['name'] is defined but when its not nothing happens, because in this case it is still not defined. So we didn't solve the issue I guess

Comment: If you look at this link - http://pastebin.com/M4RTwjSx - and check the code, it should be clear how to use the error checking.

Comment: I get that :) but what I need is to have action= "email.php" because I need not only to validate the email but do something with the data from the form

Comment: so how can a variable defined in email.php (i.e. $error) be seen by my form after I press submit

Comment: Well, to pass data between files you'll probably have to use php sessions, cookies or url parameter data.