# error when trying to display message below field

Tags: php, html

I want to give out an error message below the required field of my contact form if the field is empty. I followed this link

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237655/display-form-validation-errors-next-to-each-field
```

My code is as follows:

send.php

```
$error = array(
        "name" => "",
        "email" => "",

        "message" => ""
    );

    if(empty()$_POST["email"])
        $error["email"] = "Email is required!";

        if(empty()$_POST["name"])
        $error["name"] = "Name is required!";
        if(empty()$_POST["message"])
        $error["message"] = "Message is required!";
```

But Im getting error as:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$' in send.php on line 20
```

Line 20 is `if(empty()$_POST["email"])`

What mistake is there in my code?

Comment: `if(empty($_POST["email"]))` ditto for the others

Answer (score 1):

Fix the [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) checks. And it's probably better to add [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

from

```
if(empty()$_POST["email"])
```

to

```
if(!isset($_POST["email"]) || empty($_POST["email"]))
```

Comment: Ya i corrected as per your instructions, I have even edited in my html form as per the tutorial in the above link. But Im not getting the messages

Comment: what do you mean by not getting the messages? are you  sending mail to yourself?

Comment: How are you outputting the messages?

Comment: `isset` will return true if a post field `email` was sent even if it was blank with no value

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, before passing the strings to `empty` dont forget to do `trim`, and use `isset` also

```
<?php
  $error  = array(
    "name"    =>  "",
    "email"   =>  "",
    "message" =>  ""
  );

  $email  = ( isset( $_POST["email"] ) ) ? trim( $_POST["email"] ) : false;
  $name   = ( isset( $_POST["name"] ) ) ? trim( $_POST["name"] ) : false;
  $message  = ( isset( $_POST["message"] ) ) ? trim( $_POST["message"] ) : false;

  if ( !$emai ) {
    $error["email"] = "Email is required!";
  }
  if ( !$name ) {
    $error["name"] = "Name is required!";
  }
  if ( !$message ) {
    $error["message"] = "Message is required!";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but even though i added, im nt getting error messages

Comment: why use `empty`? As a value is already set above, won't `if( $email ){ //has email value }` do the same?

Comment: @PuneethP setting an error won't display it. You have to print the errors after. Add `print_r($error)` and see if it has the errors in there

Comment: @PuneethP, like he said, to display the error messages you need to use either `echo` or `print_r`

Comment: @bystwn22 I think you meant to update it to `if ( !$email )` exclamation mark missing

Comment: @bystwn22: ya i tried to display in in html form using the following code: <small class="errorText"><?php echo $error["message"]; ?></small> but im not getting