# Form validation error message next to text box

Tags: php, forms, validation

I've created a form in PHP, and want to validate the form entries next to the textbox itself. I tried the method posted in [Display form validation errors next to each field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237655/display-form-validation-errors-next-to-each-field), but it gave me an error. Here's my code:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="95%" align="right">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr valign="top">
<td><label>First Name:</label> <input type="text" size="25" maxlength="25" 
name="first_name" id="first_name" /></td>   
</tr>
```

.
.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; 
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
```

.
.

```
if (empty($first_name) && empty($last_name) && empty($email_address) && 
empty($user_age) && empty($gender) && empty($occupation) && empty($company_name) && 
empty($user_name) && empty($password)) {
?>
<td><?php  echo "Please Enter All Values"; ?></td>
<?php
}
elseif ((empty($first_name)) || (strlen($first_name)>25)) {
?>
<td><?php echo "Enter valid First Name that is less than 25 characters"; ?></td>
<?php
}
```

Comment: What kind of an error did you get?

Comment: You need Ajax. PHP only won't do it.

Comment: Note: you should replace the `&&` with `||` at the last when checking for.empty fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out. Might be useful. http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/r/required/

If you are into HTML5, try this. http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but that solved the problem without me having to edit the 'if' statements. Thanks a lot