# Can someone help me with my php/html form?

Tags: php, html, email

Hello i have a question,

i can't figure out why my script is not working as i intended. can someone help me figure out what the problem is?

My intention is to validate the form on the same page through a (php_self), so when something is not valid it will show an error through an echo function next to the input.

and the problem is that it doesn't echo the errors

----------------this is the PHP code-----------------

```
//define variables and set te empty//
$name = $email = $remark = "";
// errors // 
$ErrEmail = $ErrName = $ErrRemark = "";
// pre match //
$ErrMatchEmail = "";
// succes & fail //
$error = $succes = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']));
    $lastname = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['lastname']));
    $number = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['number']));
    $email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
    $remark = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['remark']));

    if (empty($name)) {
        $ErrName = 'Empty';
    } else {
        $ErrName = '';
    }

    if (empty($email)) {
        $ErrEmail = 'Empty';
    } else {
        $ErrEmail = '';
    }

    if (empty($remark)) {
        $ErrRemark = 'Empty';
    } else {
        $ErrRemark = '';
    }

    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email)) {
        $ErrMatchEmail = "email is not valid";
    } else {
        $ErrMatchEmail = "";
    }

    if (empty($ErrEmail) && empty($ErrName) && empty($ErrRemark) && empty($ErrMatchEmail)) {
        $to = 'contact@domain.nl';
        $subject = 'Contact Form: domain.nl';

        $body = 'test';

        $headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

        if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {

            $succes = 'form is send';
        }
    } else {
        $error = 'something went wrong';
    }
}
```

--------------And this html code----------------

```
<form action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input placeholder="Name*" name="name" type="text"/><?php echo $ErrName; ?>
    <input placeholder="Last name" name="lastname"/>
    <input placeholder="Number" name="number"/>
    <input placeholder="E-mail*" name="email"/><?php echo $ErrMatchEmail; ?><?php echo $ErrEmail; ?>
    <textarea placeholder="Remark/Question*" name="remark"/></textarea><?php echo $ErrRemark;
    <button type="submit">Send</button><button type="Reset">Reset</button>
    <?php echo $succes; echo $error; ?>
</form>
```

Comment: Just by looking over it briefly, I think you forgot an ending bracket at `<?php echo $ErrRemark;`

Comment: And what does or doesn't the code do instead...?

Comment: it doesn't echo the errors thats the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code. Multiple variables are not required for the validation of user input. I used an array to store all the errors.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['flag']) and isset($_GET['msg'])) {
    if($_GET['flag'] == 1 ) {
        echo "<span style='color: green'>$_GET[msg]</span>";
    }

    if($_GET['flag'] == 0) {
        echo "<span style='color: red'>$_GET[msg]</span>";
    }
}
?>


<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name*"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="number" name="number" placeholder="Number"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email*"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><textarea name="remarks" placeholder="Remarks/Questions*" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="btnSub"/> <input type="reset" value="Reset"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['btnSub'])) {
    $errors = array();
    if (empty($_POST['firstname'])) {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter your first name';
    } else {
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    }

    if (empty($_POST['lastname'])) {
        $lastname = '';
    } else {
        $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    }

    if (empty($_POST['number'])) {
        $number = '';
    } else {
        $number = $_POST['number'];
    }

    if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter your email address';
    } else {
        if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errors[] = 'Invalid email address supplied';
        } else {
            $email = $_POST['email'];
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST['remarks'])) {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter your remarks or question';
    } else {
        $remarks = $_POST['remarks'];
    }

    //Now check for the errors
    if (!empty($errors)) {
        $error = '';
        foreach($errors as $err) {
            $error .= $err.'<br>';
        }
        header("Location: $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?flag=0&msg=$error");
        exit;
    }

    $to = 'contact@domain.nl';
    $subject = 'Contact Form: domain.nl';

    $body = 'test';

    $headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    if(mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)){
        $success = 'Form is send';
        header("Location: $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?flag=1&msg=$success");
        exit;
    } else {
        $error = 'Something goes wrong...';
        header("Location: $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?flag=0&msg=$error");
        exit;
    }

}
```

Comment: Passing your error message in URL using GET allows user to display whatever they want and is not a really good solution for displaying messages. You should use an array (as you did) but with keys, where a key is corresponding to a field name, so you can display error for each field. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237655/display-form-validation-errors-next-to-each-field

Answer (score 0):

You check for a form field named `submit`, but there isn't in your form. Check your form validation like this:

```
if(isset($_POST))
```

Or even better

```
if(!empty($_POST))
```

Or just check the method

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

There is many way to check if the form has been submitted without depending of a specifical field check. With your check, if the field has to be deleted, your validation will not work anymore.

Comment: Also, PHP trim function is called using `trim()` and not `Trim()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change some of the line in your code first this line

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

change it to

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
```

second the button dont send information,

change this line in your HTML CODE

```
<button type="submit">Send</button>
```

To this

```
<input type="submit" value='submit'/>
```

Do same with reset button as well

second change this in in form action as well

```
action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>"
```

To

```
action=""
```

and remember this  dont send information in php

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hey I see what you mean:
1) I would first suggest that you validate on the front end with the use or `required` in html. See below

```
<form action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input placeholder="Name*" name="name" type="text" required/><?php echo $ErrName; ?>
        <input placeholder="Last name" name="lastname" required/>
        <input placeholder="Number" name="number" required/>
        <input placeholder="E-mail*" name="email" required/><?php echo $ErrMatchEmail; ?><?php echo     $ErrEmail; ?>
        <textarea placeholder="Remark/Question*" name="remark" required/></textarea><?php echo $ErrRemark;
        <button type="submit">Send</button><button type="Reset">Reset</button>
        <?php echo $succes; echo $error; ?>
    </form>
```

Furthermore you have your php post method listening $_POST["submit"] but the submit button has not been given a name. Here is how your overall code should look like:

```
<?php
//define variables and set te empty//
$name = $email = $remark = "";
// errors // 
$ErrEmail = $ErrName = $ErrRemark = "";
// pre match //
$ErrMatchEmail = "";
// succes & fail //
$error = $succes = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']));
    $lastname = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['lastname']));
    $number = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['number']));
    $email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
    $remark = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['remark']));

    if (empty($name)) {
        $ErrName = 'Empty';


    } else {
        $ErrName = '';
    }

    if (empty($email)) {
        $ErrEmail = 'Empty';


    } else {
        $ErrEmail = '';

    }

    if (empty($remark)) {
        $ErrRemark = 'Empty';

    } else {
        $ErrRemark = '';
    }

    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email)) {
        $ErrMatchEmail = "email is not valid";


    } else {
        $ErrMatchEmail = "";
    }

    if (empty($ErrEmail) && empty($ErrName) && empty($ErrRemark) && empty($ErrMatchEmail)) {
        $to = 'contact@domain.nl';
        $subject = 'Contact Form: domain.nl';

        $body = 'test';

        $headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

        if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {

            $succes = 'form is send';
        }
    } else {
        $error = 'something went wrong';


    }
}

?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input placeholder="Name*" name="name" type="text" required/><?php echo $ErrName; ?>
    <input placeholder="Last name" name="lastname" required/>
    <input placeholder="Number" name="number" required/>
    <input placeholder="E-mail*" name="email" required/><?php echo $ErrMatchEmail; ?><?php echo $ErrEmail; ?>
    <textarea placeholder="Remark/Question*" name="remark" required/></textarea><?php echo $ErrRemark;?>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Send</button><button type="Reset">Reset</button>
    <?php echo $succes; echo $error; ?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, instead of writing this:

```
<input placeholder="Name*" name="name" type="text"/>
```

add a "required" at the end, before the slash.

```
<input placeholder="Name*" name="name" type="text" required/>
```